# How to place a word document in orace apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I developed a report in oracle apex.

I need to place a word document  on the region.

Is it possible to place  a word document inside the report/blank  region.

If it is possible,can someone guide me the steps to place a word document on a report/blank region .

Or any alternative solution?

Comment: you need to edit the document or just show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may check this blog. it may solve your need

https://arrayofpointers.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/upload-and-view-a-file-imagepdfdoc-in-a-list-of-oracle-apex-page/